# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' password.php 00webhost

Tags: php, web-hosting

I am uploading my file in 00webhost free account. I use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat for password hashing. this works fine in my localhost. when I tried to upload this to 00webhost I get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/23456/public_html/lib/password.php on line 10

Comment: Is your PHP version are same in local and 00webhost? Seems the password hashing lib need PHP 5.5

Comment: could you share your code ?  (password.php)

Comment: @AmbalMani think he is referring to [password.php](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) jemz possible a php version issue you need to supply some more info of your error

Comment: `namespace` require PHP 5.3.0 or above check if your host has this.

Comment: @bansi what if the host don't have this version ?

Comment: If the host don't have >= 5.3 you can't use namespaces

Comment: you may need a lot of modification (not recommended at your level) in the code or search for another library which can run on the version of PHP you have.

Comment: If the hosting don't have the correct PHP version, you should either find another library or another hosting.

Comment: You should find another hosting server. PHP 5.3 is already behind end of life.